# Image Link won't work on mouseover when click

Tags: html, image, iframe, web, onmouseover

I created a page "Quick link" which contains an image as link and I use this page on "index" page by creating a class and iframe tag. When I click on an image on index page the link won't work and the images disappear while if I open the quick link file and click on it, it woks. Any idea how to make it work properly?

Code of index page:

```
<div class="img">
    <iframe src="quickLinks/quick-link.html" style="width:780px;height:500px;:-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; } overflow:hidden;border:none;padding:0;margin:0 auto;display:block;" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

code of quick links:

```
<div>
    <a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="scholarships_bt.png" onMouseOver="this.src='scholarships_bt2.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='scholarships_bt.png'" /</a>
    <a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="research_bt.png" onMouseOver="this.src='research_bt2.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='research_bt.png'" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="img"><iframe src="quickLinks/quick-link.html" style="width:780px;height:500px;:-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
} overflow:hidden;border:none;padding:0;margin:0 auto;display:block;" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe></div>
       </div>

Comment: code of quick links  <div>

<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="scholarships_bt.png" onMouseOver="this.src='scholarships_bt2.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='scholarships_bt.png'" /></a>

<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="research_bt.png" onMouseOver="this.src='research_bt2.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='research_bt.png'" /></a>

</div>

Comment: Just a tip. To be on the safe side, don't use HTML tag names as classes. This can break some browsers and could cause problems. For example, you have `<div class="img">`. IMG is an HTML tag.